# how to create page visiter counter in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to create page view counter when customer visit our website. How can I code it in codeigniter ?

[image: click here to view image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to see this post [Hit Counter in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684064/hit-counter-in-codeigniter[/link])

and also [Codeigniter: how to do hit counter for each news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222184/codeigniter-how-to-do-hit-counter-for-each-news[/link])

to know more you need to visit 
http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/how_to_build_unique_visitors_counter_with_codeigniter

Hope thats helps.